# How to create Datasets in Einstein

Tags: analytics, einstein, data-set

I have just installed the Einstein application in my Salesforce org and when I select the analytics studio application, I do not get the option to create a new "Datasets" in Analytics studio.
a)Why don't I get this option whereas I'm able to see this in the trial org which Salesforce provides.
b)How can I solve this problem and create new datasets.

Comment: you might want to do [Einstein Intent API Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/einstein_intent_basics/units/einstein_intent_basics_dataset) .

Comment: @glls, I'm not using the API, I want to create a new dataset from the Analytics UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into the same issue...Make sure you have all the appropriate Permission Sets and Permission License sets then also check the App, Analytics Studio,  and make sure the your profile is checked off.

Comment: The problem was resolved with the help of Salesforce support. There were some configuration problems which helped me to create Dataset and also we required one more license which helped me get out of here.